# How can we have a conditional deconstruction declaration in NodeJS

Tags: javascript, node.js, ecmascript-6

In my NodeJS project, I have a line like this:

```
const { fieldA, fieldB, fieldC, fieldD, fieldE, fieldF, ...rest } = originalObject;
```

`fieldB`, `fieldC`, `fieldD`, `fieldE` & `fieldF` are never used again in code, but as we know, the way the ES-6 deconstruction works, the `rest` object will be a new object without `fieldsA-F`. Therefore, later somewhere there is a dB operation, in a way so that `fieldsA-F` aren't upserted.

```
const updatedItem = await model.findOneAndUpdate({ fieldA }, rest, { upsert: true });
```

However, I want to conditionally include/ exclude `fieldF` in `rest`. I know it can be done on the reading side, but how do it in the assignment side?

Comment: If you know you can do it when you destructure `rest` why make your code unnecessarily complicated at this point?

Comment: As I said, conditionally I want to include ```fieldF``` in ```rest``` and conditionally not.. the workaround I found is to not deconstruct it here and then based on a condition delete it in the next line, but just if there was a nicer way to do it here itself...

Comment: The only way you can do it is to conditionally assign FieldF to `rest` and create a new object which you use, but you can't do it the way you want.

Comment: I'm wondering if [Proxy](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Proxy) may be helpful here.

Comment: It's possible to use computed properties like `const {[ takeF ? 'fieldF' : Symbol('never')]: _, ...rest} = …`. However, I would advise against using destructuring to omit properties from objects - write an `omit` function (or use a library) that makes it explicit what is happening and why; and it's easy to conditionally include a property name in the arguments. I would even advise against omitting things you don't need here, better *pick* the things that you do need - especially when updating a database model, you don't want to write arbitrary things but only whitelisted fields.

Comment: @Bergi, btw, `fieldF` needs to be declared in advance, even if not used later.

Comment: @NinaScholz Yes, that's what I don't like about this pattern: declaring variables and then not using them, which looks like a mistake - especially when mixed with variables that are used.

Answer (score 0):

You would need to create a new object and pass it in the db assignment phase

```js
const {param1, param2, param3} = require('./config.json')
const reqParam1 = true
const data = {}
if(reqParam1) data[key] = param1 // define key
updateDb(data)
```

or even better require everything and use the `delete` operator to remove the non required keys

```js
const config = {"param1": "hi", "param2": "hello"} //require("./config.json")
const reqParam1 = false
if(!reqParam1) delete config.param1
console.log(config)
```

Comment: Thanks, but I was looking for something within ES6 destructuring

Comment: As some fellow people have pointed out, it is not possible within destructuring or atleast recommended